# Position text above fixed text with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible I can keep `heading` above the `some other area` text at all times - even when the user begins scrolling the page?

How do I do this with my CSS/jQuery?

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/h49p65qa/

**CSS:**

```
* { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
}

.site-wrap {
    padding:40px 0
}

.some-other-area { }

h1 {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    top:0;
    margin:0;
}

h2 {
  padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0 20px 0;
}

.floatingHeader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: It depands much more on jquery than css. Css only add fixed position. I dont know where is the problem, you've show us working demo.

Comment: @Paulie_D The problem here is that 'some other area' goes `behind` 'heading' and becomes invisible :(

Comment: My apologies. I mean, visually, it has to always be below. So you have:
heading
some other area

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

JS:

```js
var el = $(this),
  offset = el.offset(),
  scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() + 50,
  floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", this)
```

CSS:

```css
.floatingHeader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h49p65qa/3/

Comment: Ah, I see it now. This looks like what the OP is after,

Comment: Sorry @Paulie_D - I need to work on my explanations :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible I can keep heading above the some other area text at
>   all times - even when the user begins scrolling the page?

You can simply change the *css property* `top` for `.floatingHeader` class to ensure that it is always below the `<h1>Heading</h1>`

```
.floatingHeader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 25px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

this way both of your requirements(*heading on top* and functionality of *floatingHeader*) are satisfied.

If however you are talking in context of depth, you may always change the `z-index`
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h49p65qa/4/)